# Is it possible to invite another user directly to a chat, by notifying him somehow?

Tags: support, chat

I sometimes saw that, by the system itself, I was invited to a chat, or that a moderator transformed a series of comments into a chat.

But, is there a possibility for me to reach out *directly* to another user, and to invite him for a chat?

Comment: I will add a link to a post on this on another per-site-meta ([math.meta.se]), since the answers there show also some screenshots: [How do I invite a user to chat?](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/22037) If you don't need the user to come to an already existing room, another option would be clicking on "create a new room with this user", see: [How do I contact other users?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/57537) (on [meta.se]).

Answer (score 1):

Yes, as I just discovered, this communication privilege is awarded at 100 reputation, according to the description [here](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/chat-rooms).